# Translate controller in PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

In my own MVC, written in PHP the controller is called from the rewritten URL, for instance in "https://www.example.com/user/my-account/" the controller is "user".

What would the way to go if I liked the URL to be "https://www.example.com/gebruiker/mijn-account"? The controller now would be "gebruiker" whereas the controller needed is named "user" (the Dutch word "gebruiker" translates as "user").
Any help to get me in the right direction very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

according to me you don't have to change the name of your controller by translating it, but you actually need the translated data that your controller can use. In this case i would leave "user" and "my-account" and show the translated data in your view, this means that if you have the words "user" and "my account" in your html page, you will translate those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Obviously this is the easiest way to go, but for the sake of visitor friendliness I thought I might want to have fully translated URLs.

Comment: before answering i checked on the most famous websites, take facebook for example and open a photo, you will see that the word "photo" in the url is the same for different languages. I think the maximum thing you can achieve is to have the language on your domain when switching it, such as de.example.com, en.example.com and so on.

Comment: You are right ..this might be the optimal solution ... thx